# How to use Google Extension to select a DNS A record that return from two DNS servers, and then make Chrome connect to the A record IP?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, https, dns

I want to make a Google extension, the requirement is...

(If I want to connect to `mail.mycompany.example`)

1. GE ask operation system's DNS to get an IP.
2. GE ask Google DNS over HTTPS server to get an IP.
3. If step 1's IP is private IP, use it to connect to `mail.mycompany.example`
4. otherwise, use step 2's IP to connect to `mail.mycompany.example`

How to code it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Chrome doesn't provide any way for extensions to hook into DNS resolution.

It's possible to control the browser's use of HTTP proxies using a [proxy autoconfig (PAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file -- which can be supplied by an extension using the [`chrome.proxy`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) API -- but a PAC file cannot make HTTP(S) requests, and it can only direct the browser to use a proxy, not to use an alternate IP to connect to a server.